# Php continue not working if not empty?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I am having a loop and that loop has only sticky posts in it. So my logic works like this:

*"If Sticky Posts are "EMPTY" break the loop"*. 
That code works as expected and looks like this:

```
<?php //we will get "Sticky Posts" only with this loop and exlude Featured Category
    $category = get_cat_ID('Featured');

    $col = 1; //Let's create first column


   $sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );  

$args = array(
    /* Add whatever you need here - see http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query */          
    'paged' => $paged,
    'category__not_in' => array($category),
    'post__in'  => $sticky, 
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1      
);

$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

/*Below is IMPORTANT PART*/
if($wp_query->have_posts()):?><?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : 
 $wp_query->the_post();if(empty($sticky))break;?>



    <div <?php post_class('col'.$col); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <?php if ($col == 1) echo '<div class="row">';//If column 1 create first row ?>
    <?php if ($col == 2) echo '<div class="row2">';//If column 2 create second row ?>
    <h3 class="mytitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'override' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <div class="entry"> 
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ):?>
                <div class="featured_img">
                <?php
                the_post_thumbnail();
                echo '<div class="featured_caption">' . get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt . '</div>';
                ?>
                </div><!--/featured_img-->
                <?php endif; ?>
        <?php  // let's enable more link on pages...
        global $more;
        $more = 0;
        ?>
            <?php the_content(__('Read more','override')); ?>   
            <div class="clear"></div>               
            <div class="custom_fields"><?php the_meta(); ?></div><br/>
            <p class="postmetadata">

            <?php _e('Filed under&#58;','override'); ?> <?php the_category(', ') ?> <?php _e('by','override'); ?> <?php  the_author(); ?><br/><?php the_tags(__('Tags:','override'), ', ', '<br />'); ?>
            <?php _e('Posted on:&nbsp;','override'); ?><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?><br/>
            <?php if ( comments_open() ) {
            comments_popup_link(__('No Comments &#187;','override'), __('1 Comment &#187;','override'), __('% Comments &#187;','override'));} 
            else {
            _e('Comments are disabled!','override');
            }
            ?>
            <?php edit_post_link(__('&nbsp;Edit','override'), __('&nbsp;&#124;','override'), ''); ?>
            </p>
        </div><!--/entry-->
    </div><!--/post_class-->

    <?php /*Enable Two Column Layout*/
        if($col==1) {
        $col=2;
        echo "</div>";
        }
        else if($col==2)  {
        $col=1;
         echo "</div>";
        }

    endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?><!--END if THE LOOP (Sticky)-->

<?php
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $temp;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Now before this working code I tried a different logic that goes like this:
*"If NOT EMPTY continue the loop"* so now everything in my code stays the same except:
`if($wp_query->have_posts()):?><?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : 
     $wp_query->the_post();if(empty($sticky))break;?>` 
so now that code becomes:
`if($wp_query->have_posts()):?><?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : 
     $wp_query->the_post();if(!empty($sticky))continue;?>`

Now this is where i got confused because `if(!empty($sticky))continue;` part does not work as expected because my loop CONTINUES **(returns other posts)** even if there are no "Stickies". I thought that loop will STOP if there are no stickies but it is not the case. 
My `var_dump($sticky)`
shows this if there are sticky posts`array(1) { [0]=> int(214) }` and shows this if there are no stickies`array(0) { }`.

My question is: Why the loop continues to return other posts if using `if(!empty($sticky))continue;` (i thought it will return ONLY "Stickies" if they exist and return NOTHING if they are not here. )

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, let me poit out that your logic doesn't quite agree with your code :).

From what I understand *from your code*, you want to iterate *all posts* `WP_Query()` returned, but only render sticky ones. Your `if` is inside the `wile` loop, so you have to check if the *current* post is sticky or not. However, `if(empty($sticky))` doesn't do that. It checks if there are any sticky posts *at all*. A way to check the current post would be `if(is_sticky(the_ID()))`.

Now, concerning `continue`:

From the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php):

> continue is used within looping structures to skip the rest of the
>   current loop iteration and continue execution at the condition
>   evaluation and then the beginning of the next iteration.

So as you can see, `continue` doesn't stop the loop, but rather attempts to start the next iteration ignoring the rest of the code for the current step. Which is what you want, if the *current* post is not sticky, in other words `if(!is_sticky(the_ID()))`.

However, I think you don't really need *any check at all*, since you already specified that you want `WP_Query()` to fetch only stickies (`'post__in'  => $sticky`).

See also: [this WordPress Answers topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43716/how-to-make-my-front-page-display-only-the-most-recent-sticky-post-plus-usual-w).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know well the wordpress code, but in that code, the `$sticky` variable is never updated in the while loop. So maybe you have to add `$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );` right before the if condition.